# How can I create a masked array with columns filtered out by column sum in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using python and numpy. I have an array with a number of columns, which I want to mask (not remove, in order to preserve indices) depending on whether the column sum is below a threshold. Here is what I have:

```
x_frequencies = np.sum(X, axis=0)
cutoff = np.percentile(x_frequencies, q=99)
mask = np.sum(X, axis=0) < cutoff
print(X.shape)
print(mask.shape)
print(mask[0].shape)
X_filtered = X[:,mask] # Error here
```

and the output for this is

```
(22987, 29308)
(1, 29308)
(1, 29308)
# Stacktrace
IndexError: invalid index shape
```

So I have two questions: firstly, how can I do what I'm intending to do; secondly, how can I get a 1d array out of mask (i.e. one with shape (29308,)) because I've tried reshape and flatten and neither of them are changing the shape.

**Edit:** X is a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

**SOLVED:** Had to convert mask from a matrix into an array:

```
mask = np.array(np.sum(X, axis=0) < cutoff).flatten()
```

Thank you to **Divakar** for asking about the type of X; I'm new to scipy/numpy and didn't know the difference between the matrix and array types

Comment: Is `X` an array or matrix?

Comment: X is a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

Comment: If `X` is `sparse matrix`, then `X.sum(axis=0)` is a dense `np.matrix`.  That distinction is also important.  Keep the sparse csr docs page open when working with `X`.  Don't assume `numpy` functions work right on it.

Comment: This form of masking does remove columns, and thus changes indices. But `np.ma.MaskedArray` does not work with `sparse` matrix.